# slim-rails gem crush on start `register_config_processor': wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

when I'm adding `slim-rails` to `Gemfile` and starting my app, it crashes with such error:

```
/Users/rado/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/gemsets/project/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:211:in `register_config_processor': wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 2..3) (ArgumentError)
  from /Users/rado/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/gemsets/project/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:53:in `register_preprocessor'
  from /Users/rado/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/slim-rails-3.1.1/lib/slim-rails/register_engine.rb:33:in `block in _register_engine'
  from /Users/rado/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:178:in `block in build_environment'
  from /Users/rado/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:177:in `each'
  from /Users/rado/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:177:in `build_environment'
```

My `rails version` is `5.0.0.1`
Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works if the gem is plugged in directly from GitHub:

```
gem 'slim-rails', github: 'slim-template/slim-rails'
```

Problem addressed: incompatibility of `gem 'slim-rails'` with Sprockets 4. (If you're using Rails 5 but Sprockets 3, this solution may not help.)

The `slim-rails` team have solved it in [this commit](https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails/commit/2b69604d381bc921623149953efaca81fe84992d), but for me it still crashes when I plug the gem from [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) — but works well when using the GitHub version.